Applications of the de Bruijn-Newman constant outside of the Riemann Hypothesis
According to Wikipedia,

The de Bruijn–Newman constant, denoted by Λ and named after
Nicolaas Govert de Bruijn and Charles Michael Newman, is a
mathematical constant defined via the zeros of a certain function
H(λ,z), where λ is a real parameter and z is a complex variable. More
precisely,

$$H(\lambda, z):=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{\lambda u^{2}} \Phi(u) \cos (z u) d u$$

, where $\Phi$ is the super-exponential function|super-exponentially
decaying function :

$$\Phi(u) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2\pi^2n^4e^{9u}-3\pi n^2 e^{5u} ) e^{-\pi n^2 e^{4u}}$$

and Λ is the unique real number with the property that H has only
real zeros if and only if λ≥Λ.

The de Bruijn-Newman constant is closely related to the Riemann Hypothesis, since it is known that the de Bruijn-Newman constant is not greater than 0 if and only if Riemann Hypothesis is true.
However, what makes me wonder is, is the Riemann Hypothesis the sole use of the de Bruijn-Newman constant? Are there any other applications of the de Bruijn-Newman constant(or even the integral $\int_{0}^{x} e^{\lambda u^{2}} \Phi(u) \cos (z u) d u$ in general) outside of the Riemann Hypothesis? Both pure math ones and other applications are welcomed.
I am not really an expert in this area; besides I could not find anything about the de Bruijn-Newman constant that is not related to the Riemann Hypothesis, and this is why I asked this question. And any help is appreciated!

I have never come across it in any context other than the Riemann Hypothesis. But I only know $0.00001%$ of all known mathematics.
